# Using package that is dependency of another local package

Tags: flutter, package

Let's say I have few flutter apps and I want all of them to load common local dependency(package) via path.

Like this:

[image]

The reasoning behind is straightforward - to have shared classes/helpers that used by all or most of flutter apps.

Now the `core_flutter` package have it's own packages as well.

Like this for example:

[image]

**Now the question.** Is it correct to use `core_flutter` dependencies inside apps that depend on it? Because it's kind of desired behaviour to share `core_flutter` packages across apps that depend on it.

For example if I need to use `provider` in my `app_one` that depends on `flutter_core`. Is it fine to use it without adding `provider` into `app_one` `pubspec`.

I've tested it already and it work.
The question though is it good practice / reliable.

The only issue right now I've noticed thad IDE won't autocomplete classes and imports in `app_one` that part of dependencies of `core_flutter`.

Comment: If the dependency was only used in `flutter_core` then it would be fine not to include it in your app. But if your app directly depends on the package then you should add it your app's pubspec.